# AngularJS routing view not loading

Tags: angularjs

started out playing with angular today. So totally noob with the issue. I've found tons of similar questions but nothing seems to help so I decided to try with my own question.

My problem is with routing. I have two views (or partials). My first view (default) loads nicely when I browse to my page. When clicking the link that should open my second view the URL changes but nothing happens. If I then hit browser refresh button the view loads.

Index page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/angular_route.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/angular_animate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular_cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
<body style="padding:10px;" ng-app="rispa">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var rispa = angular.module("rispa", ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
rispa.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/welcome', 
            {
                controller: 'rispaController', 
                templateUrl: 'partials/welcome.html' 
            })
        .when('/accounts', 
            {
                controller: 'rispaController', 
                templateUrl: 'partials/accounts.html' 
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/welcome' })
});
rispa.controller('rispaController', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Home Page";
});
```

welcome view(default)

```
<div class="container">
   <h1>Welcome!!!</h1>
    <a href="#/accounts">get accounts</a>
</div>
```

accounts view

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>accounts</h1>
    <a href="#/welcome">back to welcome</a>
</div>
```

I've got a WAMP server on Windows 10 where I run the app. I also tried to publish to a azure webapp but the view did not refresh there either. I had to click the browser refresh button so it shouldn't be a web server issue...

Comment: Ah, found the issue... I removed the ngAnimate depency and now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aCpOumYzy94ATMXiA5KR?p=preview

The routing has been set up correctly but you did not add the reference to the controller for the view. Also, you would need the dependency file for `ngAnimate` in the main view.

`<div data-ng-view="" data-ng-controller="rispaController" ></div>`

Comment: Yeah, issue was with the ngAnimate. Thanks for the answer :)